What is the best way to close this small gap in the tile?
I recently installed a new tub, and it's smaller than my old tub. There's now a gap between my existing tile. What is the best way to fix this and make it look nice?


Did you replace the tub but not the tile, or something?

Assuming that the loose tiles shown are what's available, I'd take Traveler's suggestion, but tweak it slightly.
Using a diamond blade on a wet tile saw, cut strips off one of each of the two colours of tile, across the narrow edge, and fit them alternately to make a decorative strip along the gap. Position the tiles so that you have an equal cut at either end.

You could even take this further and cut squares to make a mosaic strip.

That should look very pretty when it is done.

@DMoore the gap looks  close to 1"... Not unreasonable to put tile into a 1 inch gap. As to your second concern about grout + water from the tub. Water proof grout has been a thing for at least 20 years, and it works pretty well.

Once all the walls are finished, add a 1/4 round just as you have at the baseboards.
No nails are needed. Attach it with acrylic caulk and hold in place with tape if needed.
Paint to match the baseboards and it all looks continuous.

Might need to search around to find something large enough, (or rout your own if you have the tools/skill) but this is exactly what I would do, having fitted relevant packing beneath.

There are also quarter round tile pieces available. Might be hard to find a good match, through.

Move the tub to close the gap, pack out the far wall with some strips of wood on the studs to compensate.

How does one recenter the tub drain over the flange?

@AdamO one loosens any fasteners that are supporting the drainpipe, moves the tub, then refastens?

it depends on how hard you want to work or how perfect you want it.....an easy way would be to use a piece of wood trim and fit it there.......but if you are a perfectionist kind of person....then cut small pieces of tile and match them in to the large tiles

No, if you're a perfectionist  you want equal size tiles at all edges so you have to rip up the whole floor and do-over.

@AdamO  looks like a wooden floor so it's not too hard to adjust the pipes from underneath, or from above while tub is not in place.  many traps offer some adjustment. or possibly use a heat gun to demostrate that that plasic pipes have a noodle nature.

Supposing sufficient skill from the handypersons involved, this would be the most time-efficient and least effort-involved solution, even accounting for the time to adjust the plumbing fixtures - if fortune smiles on you, they'll be installed with flex fittings that have some play to the tolerance for fitment anyways!

To be clear, this will be take less time, labor, and skill than laying down a narrow strip of tiles.

Its nice looking.
Use a table top diamond saw and cut a appropriate size strip.
Go very slow and use a lot of water so it does not break.

Options with notes:

Cut the tile and install new tile.   CRAZY!!!   First there is almost a zero chance you aren't going to nick up or damage existing tile.    Second the gap isn't even and a row of slanted thin tiles will not look good.   The existing tiles look great, leave them alone!!!

Move the tub.   This is certainly viable and a great option but you will have to fur out the back of the tub and the hard part, move the drain.   If you just need to cut a piece of pvc and have access, this is certainly viable and maybe just an hour or two of work and not messing up the tile.

Add a trim piece like a shower threshold.  Note the amazon example is just an example.   I would personally try to get the same material and color as tub.    You cut this to size and caulk it down and it looks like it came with the tub.



Cheap and cheerful: cut a length of card, or something waterproof if you prefer. So it nearly fills the gap, height wise.
Put masking tape along (l>r) the floor and the bottom of the tub.
Use silicone (colour to suit) to bridge the gap, smoothing out with a moistened finger.
When it's gone off, remove the masking tape.

This gap looks too big for caulk, even with the height shimmed up.

The caulk won't mind, but it'll look terrible in a year.

It would be nice to know the width of that gap?! If it's 1" or a bit more, there are 1" x 6" finger tiles that will fit perfectly. If it's less than 1", than I'd put a thin layer of mastic on the plywood, and cover that with the color grout your currently using. At that point, I'd agree with a prior note that you could than add a 1/4 round of an appropriate size, and color. The 1/4 round will fill the view with its glazed surface, and there might just be enough of the grout to show a fine finished job.
